# UnicodeEncodeError in pulling tweets charmap cannot encode

Tags: python, twitter

I am trying to pull tweets from my timeline. But I am able to retrieve only half of them. It is throwing charmap codec cannot encode character u "\u2026". characters map to undefined.
I tried different encodings utf-8,ASCII, latin-1 and cp1252. But I am getting the same result. So I think the encoding is not getting changed.How should I change the encoding and which encoding should I choose for pulling tweets. I am using windows 7 and python 2.7.8.  This is my code

```
import tweepy
import csv 
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = '' 
access_secret = ''
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
data = api.get_user('')
# Open/Create a file to append data
csvFile = open('hollywood.csv', 'a')
#Use csv Writer
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile, delimiter=' ')
i = 0
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline).items():
    #Write a row to the csv file/ I use encode utf-8
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode('cp1252')])
    print tweet.created_at, tweet.text
    i+=1
    if i%5 == 0:
        print i
csvFile.close().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
tweet.text.encode('utf8')
```

UTF-8 is bulletproof in this sense. U+2026 can't be encoded in Latin1 and the rest.

Works perfectly:

```
>>> u"\u2026".encode('utf8')
'\xe2\x80\xa6'
```

Comment: I tried utf8 latin-1 cp1252 ascii. But they are throwing same error for same tweet. Is my code correct? Am I changing the encoding scheme correctly?

Comment: @AbhishekSharma sorry I can't say if it is correct or not (look ok though) because I have not used that lib. I showed you isolated example, UTF8 can encode that character without problems. You need to isolated your problem, I can't run your code.

Comment: Is there any other method for changing the encoding of output result.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma I don't get it, I show you code that works, you can try it yourself easily. Isolate your problem, reproduce and fix.

Comment: And I told you I am getting the same error for the same tweet at the exact same position with every encoding that I tried(utf8 and the remaining). So basically it does not matter what encoding I use if it is not getting changed in my code.

Comment: Error is thrown by this line                                      print tweet.created_at, tweet.text.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma I just ran the code against my tweets and it works if I use 'utf8'. I seriously don't know what you are doing. Maybe you are not running the latest code of something, the actual problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell the OS which encoding to use when writing to the file, in this case  `utf8` and also encode the text fed to the writer.

Try

```
tweet.text.encode('utf-8')

csvFile = open('hollywood.csv', encode = "utf-8", mode = 'a')
```